# EF Code First: why is entity detached after finding it?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am developing a small web application and I decided to work with Entity Framework (v6.1.x) Code First. 
I want to create a new database entry - an "offer". On the "Offer" class the "Customer" to whom the offer belongs is also stored.

Alright, nothing special, I guess...
Before I create a new offer, I retrieve the customer from the database. 
I create the new offer and set the Customer property. After calling SaveChanges on the context, I have a duplication of the customer in the customer database. After doing some debugging, I found out, that the customer-entity hast EntryState Detached... WHY?

Here are some code snippets:

MVC Controller

```
 var customer = default(Customer);
 if (model.SelectedCustomerID > 0)
            customer= _customerRepository.FindById(model.SelectedCustomerID );

// create new instance of offer
var offer = new Offer
{
  // set all necessary properties
  // ...
  Customer = customer
}

_offerRepository.AddOffer(offer);
_offerRepository.Save();
```

Customer Repository.cs

```
private readonly IDatabaseContext _context;

// DatabaseContext is injected by AutoFac
public CustomerRepository(IDatabaseContext context)
{
     _context = context;
}

public CustomerFindById(long id)
{
    return _context.Customer.Find(id);
}
```

OfferRepository.cs

```
private readonly IDatabaseContext _context;

// DatabaseContext is injected by AutoFac
public OfferRepository(IDatabaseContext context)
{
     _context = context;
}

public void AddOffer(Offer offer)
{
    // _context.Entry(offer.Customer) --> Detached
    _context.Offers.Add(offer);
}
```

I honestly cannot understand why the customer entry is detached.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: is `IDatabaseContext` injected as a singleton? if it's not - then two different contexts are injected and of course entity from another context won't be attached.

Comment: my guess is that `Customer` and `Offer` are coming from 2 different context.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ieaglle and SOfanatic.

The problem was the configuration of my IoC container (Autofac). It injected a new DatabaseContext in every Repository. Therefore I had two different context in offerRepository and in customerRepository.

I figured out, that the method InstancePerLifetimeScope() on the DatabaseContext registration was missing

AutfacConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<DatabaseContext>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
            .As<IDatabaseContext>();

    // further registrations

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

Comment: it will fix your issue, but it's very bad IMO to have single context per application lifetime. this can lead to number of bugs. it should be per call. each call has to be isolated from others. then you will need to attach entity by yourself, but it's completely fine.